# List Edit Item Menu not showing up for Documents in Document Set

Tags: 2013, document-library, document, document-set, menu

This is only happening on one Document Library. We have a Documents Set/Document layout.

When we try to edit the properties of any of the documents inside of a Document Set, the list item menu does not appear.

- This does not happen with docs outside of the doc-sets.
- This only happens on this one document library (built from a previous working library)
- This happens for all types of files contained.
- This happens for all existing (some 200+ items) and new document sets
- There are no custom additions to the List Edit Item Menu.

Comment: The Problem was with the existing view. I was even able to clone the view and save and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi @Jay Miller , In case you have solved your issue, please provide a detailed answer to help future visitors. Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a simplistic answer, the view that is shown on the document set page can be customized - did someone select the name of the document instead of the name with the list menu attached? It's defined in the content type, 'Document Set Settings' link. Down near the bottom of the page, there's a 'Welcome Page View' where the view is defined.
Check the view to see if it's using the correct name field.